# Добавление элемента с помощью AJAX и история

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Добавляю некий элемент на страничку с помощью AJAX. Потом перехожу по ссылке. Когда ворачиваюсь назад, элемент не сохранился в истории и, естественно, отсутствует. Но, обновляя страничку по F5, элемент появляется, потому что я его добавил в базу во время AJAX-вызова.

Может быть использовать функцию history.pushState() ?

Answer (score 1):

Одним из простых решений будет хранить данные полученные `AJAX`'ом в `sessionStorage`, например. Тогда можно, при переходе назад, смотреть в `sessionStorage` и обрабатывать данные из него, как будто они получены `AJAX` запросом.

Если время работы со страницей больше времени сессии, тогда можно хранить в `localStorage`.

Comment: Одним из простых решений? Уж проще обновить всю страницу location.reload();

Comment: А history.pushState не пользовались?

Comment: [history.pushState](http://caniuse.com/#search=history.pushState), а [localStorage](http://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage). Эксплоеры... И я, честно признаться, думал, что `history.pushState()` только добавляет url в историю и все.

Comment: @sitev_ru, [на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) неплохая инструкция. Так что можно и через него, если данных не много.